# how to increment a let variable without calling/creating a listerner function

Tags: javascript

In javascript we have addEventlister, this listens to an even and calls a function called a listener function. Is an alternate approach possible where we increment the value of a "let variable" without using a function to do this in case of event being triggered?

**Instead of this**

```
let clickVar = 0;
x.addEventListener("click", RespondClick);
function RespondClick() { 
            clickVar++;
        }
```

**Sample Alternate implementation**

```
x.addEventListner(click);
if (event == true){ clickVar++;  }
```

*======Edit======*

**Responding to the comment**

> The more I read this, the more it seems like an XY problem - is there something else you are trying to solve?`

In my view, the second approach is more intuitive. i.e. why create a function unless it's absolutely necessary.

**Responding to the comment**

> There is no logic to how the second approach. The code you write will be executed once. If you want to run code more than once, you have to call a function. In order to run a function when an event happens, you need an event listener.

This simple amendment should take care of the one-time calling problem.

```
x.addEventListner(click);
if (event == true){ clickVar++; event=false; }
```

But the point I am trying to make is function could have been avoided, the code could be easy enough to speak, not only write.

Comment: You cannot reassign a `const`, that's the entire reason for its existence.

Comment: Also "without using a function"? You aren't running ant code on click, so why would anything change when clicking, then?

Comment: @VLAZ let me replace it with let then

Comment: If you use `let`, the problem is solved.

Comment: The more I read this, the more it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - is there something *else* you are trying to solve?

Comment: @YongQuan except the problem of not running any code and yet expecting code to run...

Comment: @VLAZ I thought the problem was in the first code snippet where it was initially `const` instead of `let`. Now I realised it's the second snippet.

Comment: @VLAZ i answerd your comment in the Edit

Comment: There is no logic to how the second approach. The code you write will be executed once. If you want to run code more than once, you have to call a function. In order to run a function when an event happens, you need an event listener.

Comment: Your second approach doesn't make any sense at all -- what is `click`? What is `event`? When does it equal `true`? How is the JavaScript engine supposed to know when to execute it? There is no way that could be valid code without redefining basically all of JavaScript.

Comment: I disagree with the "easy to speak" or "easy to write". The construct you've shown has no logic to it. When you say `addEventListener("click", someFunction)` it's completely intuitive to think of it as "any time you click, run someFunction". The proposed way has no such clarity - there is no link between the event listener and the code after it, if there was, then how do you determine where it ends? Is it the fist statement after the event listener? Anything until the end of the file? Until the end of the function? What if you want to re-use the code elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your second sample doesn't work. That simply isn't how event listeners work. You must use a callback function. If you think the first sample is too verbose, you can use an anonymous function:

```
let clickVar = 0;

x.addEventListener("click", function() {
  clickVar++;
});
```

Or an arrow function in more modern versions of Javascript

```
x.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clickVar++;
});
```

Comment: An even shorter implmentation with an arrow function will omit the `{}` brackets and the newlines `x.addEventListener("click", () => clickVar++);`

Comment: In my opinion the second snippet of yours is not user friendly at all . you can write it but you cannot speak it. If the creators of javascript had left an option to implement it like my sample approach atleast it would be user friendly and easy on beginners who don't wan't to learn too much new syntax.

Comment: Why should you be able to speak it? The majority of programming languages have things that can't "be spoken" -- it's not meant to be.

Comment: @DeskiRey Nobody claimed Javascript was perfect. After all, it was designed in a couple of weeks :-)

Comment: @Herohtar What would be so wrong if you could also speak what you write? we are not trying to create a code language to hide from non-programmers anyway. We, programmers, create jibberish looking code and then write Pages of documentation trying to explain it. does that look more logical? not to forget programming is all about logic implementation

Comment: Lots of things... there are programming languages that were created to look as much like regular language as possible and they are a pain to work with. They're much less efficient to write, and the more like a human language they are the more difficult they are for the computer to parse.